# How can I make outbound requests from two servers that appear to come from the same IP address

Tags: ip, amazon-web-services, ip-routing

I am making calls from an ec2 instance to a third party web service (over which I have no control).  I would like to be able to scale horizontally, so that I can make these calls from multiple ec2 instances, but the web service I'm calling whitelists my IP, and for the sake of discussion let's assume I can't get another IP address whitelisted.

How can I send requests from 2+ machines that appear to the web service to be from the same IP address?  Thanks!

Comment: What would most likely be the bottleneck resource that would require more instances? CPU, memory, network?

Comment: Probably memory would be the first to matter (and then cpu).

Comment: Well, then +1 for the Brents answer (move to VPC and use NAT instance)

Comment: Isn't this basically what a load balancer does for you?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are really looking for some sort of NAT translation within EC2.  I'm not sure if you can set this up with simple EC2 instances but I know they offer it as part of their [VPC offering](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#G1)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a proxy server and send requests through that proxy server to the web services server. Or VPC NAT is other option for you

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any idea how to set up such a proxy server? We use apache for load-balancing internally (which I believe makes it a reverse proxy?), any idea if I can use apache to solve this problem? For example, a single apache box which has the whitelisted IP, and many boxes sending requests through that box to the 3rd-party service?